# Waiting for a promise to finish before running a second javascript file?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have two javascript files. The first, request.js, fetches a JSON from a URL and formats the data assigning it to a global variable. The second, main.js, uses the data from the global variable. The issue I'm running into is that the second javascript file runs before the request from the URL is resolved. Is there any way to prevent the rest of the program from running until the promise is resolved without calling a function from main.js in request.js?

request.js:

```
...
fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        organiseData(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        throw err
    });
...
```

main.js:

```
...
loadImages(submissionArr, categoriesMap);
...
```

edit:
I'm trying to avoid explicitly calling the request.js file inside of the main file as I plan to use it with other javascript files as well.

Comment: Just load the file main.js later. Instead of adding a ```require('....main.js')``` at the top of the file, load it once the response is received.

Comment: You could have request.js add the main.js script tag instead of doing it directly. This architecture is agnostic to js paradigms and you should use a callback tough

Comment: "*assigning it to a global variable*" - there's your problem, don't do that. Instead, store a promise as a constant global, which your main.js can access at any time

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the fetch in a function and return it's promise so you can do something like:

```
function getData() {  
    // return the fetch promise  
    return fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {       
            organiseData(data);
            // optionally return data if needed it down the chain
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw err
        });    
}
```

Then call it from main:

```
getData().then(data = > loadImages(submissionArr, categoriesMap);)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, returning a promise always helps since you can `.then` chain them together

It seems like you may not have control over the various files in your project, like some are from external vendors? If so here's a solution. It's not ideal and requires that those functions exist on those files and never change, but it works. Also all these globals are not a good idea but if you really no option due to your external vendors, I get it.

```html
  <script src="request.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <script>
    const data = {};

    function setGlobal(data) {
      window.data = { ...window.data, ...data };
      // function inside of main.js will read global
      organiseData();
    }

    // function inside of request.js
    getData()
      .then((data) => setGlobal(data))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
  </script>
```

Here's a codesandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-antonelli-u5tdk?file=/index.html